# Laravel 5 - defining relationships

Tags: laravel-5

everything was working fine with a single Model, but now I am implementing more, I have noticed an issue.

I have several document Models which represent a different type of document.  For now, let's say I have DocumentA and DocumentB.

Each Document allows file uploads, so I have created a FileUpload Model.  A Document can have many FileUploads.

So, seems pretty straight forward at this point.  My FileUpload table has a documentId field, which is a reference to the id field of the Document that is using it.

In DocumentA, I have something like so

```
public function uploadFile()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\UploadFile', 'documentId');
}
```

So DocumentA can have many UploadFiles, linked by the documentId.

DocumentB has the same function within its Model.

My problem lies with the UploadFiles model.  Firstly, this model now has two belongTo events e.g.

```
public function documentA()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\DocumentA', 'documentId');
}

public function documentB()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\DocumentB', 'documentId');
}
```

This could be the problem, not sure if I can have multiple belongs to?  My immediate problem however is to do with the migration of the doc_file table.  At the moment I have this

```
Schema::table('doc_file', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->integer('documentId')->unsigned()->default(0);
    $table->foreign('documentId')->references('id')->on('document_a')->onDelete('cascade');
});

Schema::table('doc_file', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->integer('documentId')->unsigned()->default(0);
    $table->foreign('documentId')->references('id')->on('document_b')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

So I am trying to provide foreign keys to my documents.  When I try to migrate, it tells me that

> Column already exists: 1060 Duplicate column name documentId

Am I handling my relationships correctly?  Essentially, I have many documents, and each document can have many files.

Any assistance with my database relationships appreciated.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your problem at first glance, it seems that there is a little confusion for you regarding the concept *model*.

### The Model Concept

A model is in fact a *conceptualization* of a real-world object as it is used to represent a real-world entity.

In other words, it represents a whole class of objects with similar properties. For instance a Car model would represent all cars, whether they are of type *Lamborghini* or *Mercedez*. The fact is that they **all** come under the *Car* classification.

Same concept goes in Eloquent, and with your use case; therefore a *Document* model is sufficient to represent both of your documents (DocumentA and DocumentB).

### Eloquent Relationships

To refine what you've achieved so far, your models' relationships can be refactored as such:

*Document Model*

```
public function fileUploads(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\FileUpload');
}
```

*FileUpload Model*

```
public function document(){ 
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Document');
}
```

Based on the relationship *"EACH document has MANY file uploads"*, and the inverse *"EACH file upload BELONGS to exactly one document"*, as you can see, there is only *one* `belongsTo()` method in the FileUpload model to define the latter part of the relationship.

Similarly, the schema for the tables defining the above relationship are as follows:

```
// Schema for Document table
Schema::table('document', function (Blueprint $table) { 
    $table->increment('id'); 
    $table->string('name', 100);
});

// Schema for FileUpload table
Schema::table('doc_file', function (Blueprint $table) { // file_uploads would have been a more friendly name in my opinion
    $table->integer('documentId')->unsigned()->default(0);   // note that `documentId` is interpreted as `documentid` in MySQL
    $table->foreign('documentId')->references('id')->on('document')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. One thing however.  I have several Document models, because each document is unique.  How would that fit into this scenario?

Comment: To further clarify, each document has different inputs.  I can't think of a way of using a single Document model because they are so unique.

Comment: Can you denote shortly as to what (input) exactly makes those documents unique?
Even if your documents are unique, their uniqueness can be determined with primary keys.

Comment: For instance, one document has 3 normal inputs and a text area.  Another document accepts dates, text fields, and select fields.  I can't see how one document model can represent all of these documents as they are not taking the same data.

Comment: In that case you have two options: `1` Add another field to your `Document` model which holds the structure for the document, which is possible by getting the structure as a PHP array, and then `json_encode`ing it to be stored. `2` Create another model (e.g. `DocStructure` for the same purpose and define the relationship of this model with your Document model as a _one-to-one_.

Comment: Note that, it's quite unclear for me as to what strategy have you implemented to get the structure of a particular document, as the above is based on my own conjecture.

Comment: I have yet to implement a strategy, this is what I am trying to solve.  Trying to figure out how to create multiple different document types