# Laravel 5.5: Relationship with Multiple different sub-models

Tags: php, laravel, model, relationships

I am working on an application for our library.

We have different document types (Gazettes, books, reports, newspaper clippings, etc.

I started off creating a model for Gazettes, with fields like name, year, number, type of regulation/law, reference. When working on file uploads, I made the relationship with the file.

So the idea is to have one `Resource` class for all the documents, and a model for each document type, since the fields differ. Newspaper clippings would have  `body, newspaper, date and page` as fields. Books would have a whole lot more, like `title, subtitle, author, publisher, genre, ISBN, hard/soft`.

I should be able to link files to each, either as digital version of the document or as "relevant".

I am thinking of a many to many relationship between the model for files and resource, but how do I still incorporate the differing fields of each sub-model. One where I don't have to make a relationship for each document type individually (gazette_file and book_file and report_file) especially since they should be interchangeable.

What model/relationship structure do I use?

There is a ALMOST similar question [Laravel 5 - defining relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34318009/laravel-5-defining-relationships), but the focus is different. The provided answer does not take the differing fields into consideration.

Comment: This sounds like basic OOP. Make a main Document class then inherit that parent class in each specific document type object. Then make a main Resource object. Give the parent Document object a has many relationship with the Resource object.

Comment: Coming from procedural background, I'll quickly look into OOP before continuing here. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a Polymorphic relationship.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations

So your files model will have an "id" field and a "type" that relates to the model the file is associated with.

E.g.

```
Book with the ID of 99

Files Model

id = 1
related_id = 99
related_type = book
file_name = "yourname.jpg"
etc
```